# Given that 门店 (lit. "door shop") = "outlet", how do you say "door shop"?

Tags: translation

> 门店 (mén​diàn​)
> [CC-CEDICT](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E9%97%A8%E5%BA%97): (retail) store

(We might otherwise translate 门店 to "[outlet](http://youdao.com/w/eng/%E9%97%A8%E5%BA%97)".)

This raises the question as to what you would call a shop that sells doors, given that 门店 (which literally translates to 门 = "door" and 店 = "shop") has another meaning.  If I were to guess, I'd say 门店 also means "door shop" and the listener can deduce this from the context.  However, Baiduing [`"去门店买门"`](https://www.baidu.com/s?wd=%22%E5%8E%BB%E9%97%A8%E5%BA%97%E4%B9%B0%E9%97%A8%22) doesn't give much, so I'm not sure.

**Question**: Given that 门店 = "outlet", how do you say "door shop"?

Comment: Is "a shop that sells doors" a real thing? @_@ I just asked my boyfriend where I can buy doors, and he said  "建材城 家具城". (Here 城 means a big marketplace.) If you really need to say "a shop that sells doors", you can say 卖门的店. lol

Comment: I recall in Melbourne there are door shops: [Doors Galore](https://doorsgalore.com.au/) and [Doors Plus](https://www.doorsplus.com.au/).  Do other places not have them?  (Aside from [real fake doors on Rick and Morty](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4270c5qWPBg).)

Comment: I just searched and it seems that 卖门的店 is indeed used even by the door shop owners. see https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/96871767.html and its related questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term 门店 (outlet; retail store) is usually tied to a brand name or a manufacturer's name

Example:

- Apple Store is a **retail store** that belonged to Apple, which sells only Apple products (苹果商店是苹果公司的**门店**)
- 到某门窗厂的**门店**选购门窗 (Go to the **outlet store** of a door and Window factory to buy doors and windows)

If you say 去门店買门, you are implying that the store only sells doors and nothing else. but in reality, a store that mainly sells door also sell windows and related products, they are called 门窗專門店

Therefore, saying 去门窗(專門)店買门 is more natural than saying 去门店買门

And there are other places you can find doors to buy, e.g. 裝修公司，百貨公司，五金店，建築公司 and so on. None of them is just '**a door store** (一間门店)' but some of the locations could be '**a company's retail store** (某公司的门店)'

Answer (score 1):

門業公司 or 大門設計 if you are looking for a shop that sells just doors, perhaps designer doors. But most shops carry other items as well, so it is common practice to visit a 門窗公司, 裝修公司, 廚櫃公司, or 木業公司 for the wooden product, or a 五金行 for the metallic bits.

Answer (score 1):

`门店` and `门市店` sometimes both mean `store` or `store front`.

> Given that 门店 = "outlet", how do you say "door shop"?

It is correct to use `门店` to refer to a store that sells doors, but doing so may cause confusion if taken out of context. It is very rare for a store to only sell doors. Those that do are often called `建材城` (similar to Home Depot), or `钣金店`/`五金店` (a type of sheet metal shop).